# when invoked aws lambda function always return same response

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I use Visual Studio AWS extensions in order to create simple aws lambda function using docker image template.
Docker image has been built, tagged and finally pushed to the container registry. From there I create a new lambda function using container image. But when I test it (either locally using dotnet lambda invoke-function or using Test tool on AWS console I'm getting

> Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (5.3.0) Project Home:
> https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli,
> https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet
>
> Payload: {"Lower":"test","Upper":"TEST"}
>
> Log Tail: START RequestId: 67ac52b9-8cd0-449b-9bc3-8584f31f9726
> Version: $LATEST END RequestId: 67ac52b9-8cd0-449b-9bc3-8584f31f9726
> REPORT RequestId: 67ac52b9-8cd0-449b-9bc3-8584f31f9726  Duration:
> 890.55 ms     Billed Duration: 1224 ms        Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 61 MB    Init Duration: 332.49 ms

This would be ok but I changed the internal implementation of returning my custom string instead of default one. It should return "`my custom string test`" instead of `{"Lower":"test","Upper":"TEST"}`

```
public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
{
  return "my custom string " + input;
}
```

Again, why the function returns default response over and over again.

Comment: Did you redeploy the Lamdba? It does not 'hot reload' :)

Comment: Sounds like the image registry to which your lambda is pointing is not what you think it is. Have you tried pulling the image and running the handler directly to see if it returns your custom string?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes, I redeploy the image on the lambda.

Comment: @theherk when debug locally it works as expected. I even delete all images with system prune -a and delete current image from the registry before docker build.

Comment: Your question says doing it locally also doesn’t work?

Comment: Inside debugger it works as expected but when using cli locally ex: dotnet lambda invoke-function ... it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your lambda points to the **newly deployed image** in AWS Console.

Depending on your deployment method, there is potential that your lambda was pointing to the first deployed image all the time. Your situation looks like you are using the old image all the time.

PS: both `dotnet lambda invoke-function` and `using Test tool on AWS console` are calling the deployed lambda, so it sounds reasonable that they give you the same
result.